# Can logistic and lineair regression produce a prediction on a scale?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression, training-data

I currently have a dataset of drawings, each drawing being represented by some features. Each feature (independent variable) is a continuous number. None of the drawings have a label as of yet, which is why I am planning to start a sort of questionaire with people. However, before I can correctly setup such questionaire, I should have an idea of what kind of labels I should use for my training data.

At first thought, I was thinking about letting people rate the drawings on a scale, for example from 1 to 5 with 1 being bad, 3 being average and 5 being good. Alternatively, I could also reduce the question to a simple good or bad question. The latter would mean I lose some valuable information, but the dependent variable could then be considered 'binary'.

Using the training data I then composed, I would need to have a machine learning algorithm (model) which given a drawing, predicts if the drawing is good or not. Ideally, I would have some way of tuning the strictness in this prediction. For example, the model could instead of simply predicting 'good' or 'bad', predict the likelyhood of a painting being good on a scale of 0 to 1. I could then say "Well, let's say all paintings which are 70% likely to be good, are considered as good". Another example would be that the model predicts the goodness using the same categorical values the people used to rate the drawing initially. So it would either predict the drawing being a 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. Similar to my first example, I could then say "Well, all paintings which are rated at least a 4, are considered good paintings" and tune this threshhold to my liking.

After doing some research, I came up with logistic and linear regression being good candidates. However, if which of the two would be the best for my scenario? Equally important, how would I need to format my labels? Just simple 0's and 1's or a scale?

Comment: Arguably, starting from the *tool* (here logistic regression) and looking at the details of the problem at hand only afterwards, as you seem to do here, is a completely wrong and ass-backwards approach. We don't start with the tool requirement, we start with defining & understanding the problem, and only after we have done that we look for the appropriate tool to use (and, fortunately, there are quite a few ones).

Comment: Rephrased my question, hopefully it is now more clear!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 1 vs all representation if you wanted to use a multi-class categorical classification:

Essentially, you train 1 classifier for every category you have (you have 10 categories, so you have 10 classifiers) and then each classifier is just trained to predict whether or not the category belongs to each specific class.

There are alternative ways to make multi-class logistic regression work that only require training a single model, such as by using categorical cross entropy, but given that you'd like to use ordinal data, a linear regression used as a regression model is likely more ideal. You'd predict a value between 1 and 10 and then just round to the nearest integer. This way you aren't penalizing close guesses as much as far away guesses.

Answer (score 0):

what keeps you from using a logistic regression model. Due to a lack of better dataset I used the standard diabetes data. The target variable is an integer between `50` and `200`. I normalised the data between `[-1,1]` such that I can use sigmoid as activation function. For the loss I decided to use

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, Input, Convolution2D
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()

x_train=diabetes.data
y_train=2*(diabetes.target-min(diabetes.target))/(max(diabetes.target)-min(diabetes.target))-1

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1],))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)


model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),  # Optimizer
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MSE,
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=64,
                    epochs=300,
                    validation_data=(x_train, y_train))
```

You could also use a linear regression model. There you only need to replace the activation function by linear. However I think the squashing character, besides ensuring hat there is no rating larger `1` or smaller `-1`.

A last alternative would be to train pair-wise preference. The idea is to show the human two drawings and ask which one he likes more. Then build a binary model, e.g., logistic regression. This approach appears preferable to me as it is easier to answer for the human